# Jumpy seekbar in video js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am trying to implement videojs in my reactjs application. I have uploaded a 5 second video in the player.

**Problem : The seekbar doesn't transition smoothly**

This is because videojs calls the timeupdate method in gaps. That is why the current time values are not smooth. Can I make it smooth in any way?

```
initVideoJS = ()=> {
        let x
        var myPlayer = videojs('video-el');

        myPlayer.on("timeupdate", () => {
            duration = myPlayer.duration();
            currentTime = myPlayer.currentTime();

            console.log(currentTime)
            this.setState({line1_xEnd: currentTime * 500/duration}, ()=>{
                console.log(this.state.line1_xEnd)
            })

        })
    }
```

I tried looking for the same on internet, but couldn't fine anything but this

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/4526

But this also was very confusing. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Well have you tried the fix for the issue that was suggested in there? https://github.com/loomhq/video.js/commit/80500a0d595325289262191dac2cb6adf3d42a18

Comment: Yeah I tried hard. Got stuck at Fn.throttle. What is that?